# Can I simplify the sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

**The sql is:**

```
select count(*)
  from (select *
          from T_LOGGINGINFO
          where to_char(LOGINTIME, 'YYYY-MM') = '2012-05'
          group by USERNAME)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brevity is the soul of wit (and lingerie), but clarity is the soul of code. Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT USERNAME)
  FROM T_LOGGINGINFO
  WHERE LOGINTIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-MAY-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                      AND TO_DATE('31-MAY-2012 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Clearer IMO, probably faster as TO_CHAR won't have to be executed against every row in the table, and will potentially allow an index on `(LOGINTIME, USERNAME)` to be used. YMMV.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1 lingerie lol (btw I happen to subscribe to brevity to the point of dogma too)

Comment: "Brevity is the soul of lingerie" - [Dorothy Parker](http://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/24956.Dorothy_Parker)

Answer (score 3):

```
   select COUNT(DISTINCT USERNAME)
     from T_LOGGINGINFO
    where to_char(LOGINTIME,'YYYY-MM')='2012-05'
```

A note: `to_char(LOGINTIME,'YYYY-MM')` won't allow using index for `LOGINTIME` column, unless you have a particular functional index.

Comment: Considering the index issue, would it be better use `YEAR(LOGINTIME)=2012` and `MONTH(LOGINTIME)=5` instead?

Comment: @Nizam: it depends on what indexes are created

Comment: @Nizam . . . If you wanted performance for an available index, you would do `logintime >= '2012-05-01' and logintime < '2012-06-01'`.

Comment: I try to avoid the use of functions with columns as arguments in the WHERE clause. Had a query one time that we just could not figure out - ran incredibly slow, threatened the health and safety of the free world, etc, blah. Finally realized there was an innocent little function in the WHERE that was being called 500,000 times to satisfy a query that returned about 100 rows. Converted the function call to a simple `IN` list - query finished before I could get my finger off the `Enter` key. Bug - SQUASHED! Functions in `WHERE` clause - BAD! Simplicty - GOOD! :-) YMMV. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#ADMIN11730

Comment: @zerkms: function-based indexes are verboten at my workplace. There's no reason for it; it's just our policy...